# Dos enlaces en un table view cell swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

Estoy realizando una app en `Swift 2`, y tengo un `UITableView` con tweets que obtengo con la API de Twitter, y muestro la imagen de perfil, el nombre de usuario, la fecha de publicación y el contenido del tweet. Lo que quiero es que si clico en la imagen me lleve a su perfil, y si clico en el tweet me lleve al tweet. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que dentro de un `UITableViewCell` pueda tener dos enlaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy simple, haz que al clicar en la celda te abra el tweet. Después añade un `UITapGestureREcognizer` a la imagen o bien haz que la imagen sea un `UIButton` en vez de un `UIIMageView`

Comment: me aparece este error: WARNING: A Gesture recognizer was setup in a storyboard/xib to be added to more than one view (-><UIImageView: 0x7faee8cb08a0; frame = (2 1; 50 50); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 2; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7faee8ee13a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7faee8cb18e0>>) at a time, this was never allowed, and is now enforced. Beginning with iOS 9.0 it will be put in the first view it is loaded into.  Y no me hace el clic

Comment: Añádelo por código y no en el StoryBoard

Comment: Perfecto, me ha funcionado bien, gracias